# Cannot drop postgresql role

Tags: postgresql

I've created a role in postgresql:

```
$ CREATE ROLE demo_role;
```

`$ \du` returns the role name `demo_role` with `Cannot login` under the list of roles/attributes.

I want to delete this role. If I enter the following command:

```
$ DROP ROLE demo_role;
```

It doesn't delete the role and I receive no error message. Why is this and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Where exactly are you entering that statement? Do you get any feedback from the `drop` statement? Did you maybe turn off autocommit? Then you need a `commit` after the `drop`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Within psql. No. I'm not sure.

Comment: Its case sensitive , try with quotes , see my answer

Comment: And you **did** finish the statement with `;` in psql? If you did not receive **any** feedback from psql it most probably means you didn't properly end the statement with `;`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way and also postgresh is case sensitive

```
DROP OWNED BY "demo_role";
```

and then do :

```
DROP ROLE "demo_role";
```

Comment: `DROP ROLE demo_role;` is **exactly** the same thing as `DROP ROLE "demo_role";`

Answer (score 0):

I opened pgAdmin and the `demo_role` appeared uner Group Role but not Login Role. Anyway I delete/dropped it from there and that resolved my issue.